# Replace underlying standard errors in lm() OLS model in R

Tags: r, replace, lm

I would like to run an ols model using `lm()` in R and replace the standard errors in the model. In the following example, I would like to replace each standard error with "2":

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

mod <- lm(y ~x)

ses <- c(2,2)
coef(summary(mod))[,2] <- ses
sqrt(diag(vcov(mod))) <- ses
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `mod <- summary(mod); mod['coefficients'][[1]][c(3, 4)] <- 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those assignments are not going to succeed. `coef`, `sqrt` and `vcov` are not going to pass those values "upstream". You could do this:

```
> false.summ <- coef(summary(mod))
> false.sqrt.vcov <- sqrt(diag(vcov(mod))) 
> false.summ
               Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.10280305 0.09755118 -1.0538371 0.2945488
x           -0.05247161 0.10687862 -0.4909459 0.6245623
> false.summ[ , 2] <- ses
> false.sqrt.vcov
(Intercept)           x 
 0.09755118  0.10687862 
> false.sqrt.vcov <- ses
```

You could also modify a summary-object at least the `coef`-matrix, but there is no "vcov" element in summary despite the fact that `vcov` does return a value.

```
> summ <- summary(mod)
> summ$coefficients[ , 2] <- ses
> coef(summ)
               Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.10280305          2 -1.0538371 0.2945488
x           -0.05247161          2 -0.4909459 0.6245623

> summ$vcov
NULL
> vcov(summ)
             (Intercept)           x
(Intercept)  0.009516233 -0.00103271
x           -0.001032710  0.01142304:
```

If you wanted to change the output of `vcov` when applied to a summary object you would need to distort the unscaled cov-matrix. This is the code that `vcov` uses for that object-class:

```
> getAnywhere(vcov.summary.lm)
A single object matching ‘vcov.summary.lm’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for vcov from namespace stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (object, ...) 
object$sigma^2 * object$cov.unscaled
<bytecode: 0x7fb63c784068>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed replaces those numbers, but I would like to replace it in the underlying model such that when you call `summary(mod)` the standard errors are 2. This is so that it aligns with exporting functions such as stargazer.

Comment: I gave you a lot of information and showed you how to do it for the coef-matrix inside a summary object. You don't find that useful? There is no `vcov<-` or `coef<-` function to support destructive modification of summary objects.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and code - much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose that one could imagine a language where there were assignment functions that would be able to (back)-trace the origins of previous  assigned values, but that's way too much like Macsyma or Mathematica. R has a limited number of functions that make assignments "in place". Probably for good reason. Your request struck me as exceedingly dangerous to put in the hands of naive users and I cannot imagine a statistician actually wanting to do this.